# Python: convert series object columns in pandas dataframe to int64 dtype

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, int, series

I have the following data frame:

```
Day_Part     Start_Time    End_Time   
Breakfast    9:00          11:00
Lunch        12:00         14:00
Dinner       19:00         23:00
```

The columns Start_Time and End_time are 'Series Objects' right now.  I want to convert the values in those columns into int64 dtype.

This is what I want the data frame to look like:

```
Day_Part     Start_Time    End_Time   
Breakfast    9             11
Lunch        12            14
Dinner       19            23
```

*Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first convert [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html) and then extract `hour`:

```
df['Start_Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Start_Time']+ ':00').dt.components.hours
df['End_Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['End_Time']+ ':00').dt.components.hours
print (df)

    Day_Part  Start_Time  End_Time
0  Breakfast           9        11
1      Lunch          12        14
2     Dinner          19        23
```

Another solution with [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and cast to `int`:

```
df['Start_Time'] = df['Start_Time'].str.split(':').str[0].astype(int)
df['End_Time'] = df['End_Time'].str.split(':').str[0].astype(int)
print (df)

    Day_Part  Start_Time  End_Time
0  Breakfast           9        11
1      Lunch          12        14
2     Dinner          19        23
```

Solution with [`extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) and cast to `int`:

```
df['Start_Time'] = df['Start_Time'].str.extract('(\d*):', expand=False).astype(int)
df['End_Time'] =  df['End_Time'].str.extract('(\d*):', expand=False).astype(int)
print (df)

    Day_Part  Start_Time  End_Time
0  Breakfast           9        11
1      Lunch          12        14
2     Dinner          19        23
```

Solution with convert [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
df['Start_Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start_Time'], format='%H:%M').dt.hour
df['End_Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['End_Time'], format='%H:%M').dt.hour
print (df)
    Day_Part  Start_Time  End_Time
0  Breakfast           9        11
1      Lunch          12        14
2     Dinner          19        23
```

**Timings**:

```
#[300000 rows x 3 columns]
df = pd.concat([df]*100000).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)

In [158]: %timeit pd.to_timedelta(df['Start_Time']+ ':00').dt.components.hours
1 loop, best of 3: 7.12 s per loop

In [159]: %timeit df['Start_Time'].str.split(':').str[0].astype(int)
1 loop, best of 3: 415 ms per loop

In [160]: %timeit df['Start_Time'].str.extract('(\d*):', expand=False).astype(int)
1 loop, best of 3: 654 ms per loop

In [166]: %timeit pd.to_datetime(df['Start_Time'], format='%H:%M').dt.hour
1 loop, best of 3: 1.26 s per loop
```